# Facebook App doesn't work in mobile devices, SSL connection not found

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I'm creating a facebook app in the developers side of facebook.

Everything is working when I start browsing the app via browser, but when I try to access the app via a mobile device I get a message like this:

"Secure connection not found"

It is strange because my app URL is a SSL page, we have created our certificate and it expire in 10 years..

Someone have got the same problem in the past?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a HTTPS enabled mobile site URL under your App's settings? I guess this could be the reason...

Comment: I can't find the "HTTPS enabled mobile site URL" in app's setting, I'm using "App on Facebook", with URL main page and Secure Canvas URL filled with the correct url.

Comment: You need to use the "add a new platform" button on the bottom to create a mobile site URL entry

Comment: but in this case my mobile device will open a browser page.. and opening a browser page the customer have to re-login on my app, because I can't take his personal information

Comment: I don't really understand, you wrote "browsing the app via browser"... What does this mean then?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the self-signed certificate, with a new and not self-signed certificate everything works!